# Web service with a generic payload XML type "Any"

Tags: spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, tibco

I have developed a web service that accepts and responds with a common message structure. Meaning, this message structure is made to be generic. The way we made it generic is using the following XML schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="HeaderType">
<xs:complexType name="MessageType">
<xs:complexType name="PayloadType">
```

where PayloadType is the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="PayloadType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Payload container</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>

                <xs:element name="CreateExceptionSeverity" type="cmsmsg:ExceptionSeverity" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>CreateExceptionSeverity is a hello world operation that takes in a app id, id, name, and description where the web service creates a new entry in EXCEPTIONSEVERITY table.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="OperationSet" type="cmsmsg:OperationSet" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Each operation set is a collection of operations that may require operational-integrity and/or sequence control.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Compressed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>For compressed and/or binary, uuencoded payloads</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                **<xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" namespace="##other">**
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>For XML payloads, usually CIM profiles defined using an XSD in a profile-specific namespace.</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                </xs:any>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Format" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Hint as to format of payload, e.g. XML, RDF, SVF, BINARY, PDF, ...</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

So, the line:

```
<xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" namespace="##other">
```

makes this structure flexible enough to send data when invoking the web service and when the web service sends back the response. This web service is deployed on a TIBCO server (uses Tomcat) and will be invoked through way of SOAP/HTTP.

The client for this web service is a Java Spring web app. My question is: how can the Java code deal with this Any element because it requires a concrete XML type like integer, string, or a complex type? Any direction here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't do this. I've worked with these sort of "generic" web services before and they are the equivalent of having a java API where every method has the signature

```
public Object methodName(Object o);
```

Yes, it's all very generic, but it conveys no information on how to use it (A well designed interface conveys how it should be used, the same way the handle of a tea pot suggests that the tea pot should be picked up by the handle). When someone wants to develop an application that consumes your service, how do they figure out what to send and what they'll get back? If it's in some other document, then you've basically created your own bespoke web service description language, which won't integrate with any tooling (like Spring or Axis-2) and will require a lot of extra manual code to be written.

Additionally, you're going to have to write extra code in your service implementation to validate the content of the payloads. This means extra work to maintain and higher chance of defects.

Please use concrete XML inputs and responses for your Web Service operations and get rid of the any's. Not only will it make your code simpler and the code of your consumers simpler, it will also get rid of the question you've ask on how to consume it from Spring.

The fact that you've had to come here to ask how to consume a web service you've created should be setting off alarm bells in your head. When creating any sort of interface, if it's hard for you to use, then it's going to be extremely hard for anyone else to use. To ensure my web services are easy to consume, the first thing I do (before I create the WSDL or the implementation) is create a simple program that invokes the service as part of a test(e.g., JUnit or Cucumber-JVM, etc), passing in only the data that's needed (and nothing more) and only checking for the response data that it needs (and nothing more). I then work on the web service implementation until the test passed. This always results in nice easy and simple to use services, rather than big heavy bloated services with highly complex schemas, of which only 1% is used (I'm sure they put the other 99% of the schema there and don't use it, just to lead new users of the service astray).

In terms of the meta-data you want to include in the message (i.e. the messageType and headerType information), consider using [SOAP Headers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tipjax1.html) as per the [Messaging Metadata SOA Pattern](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/messaging_metadata). They allow you to include extra information, without polluting your message body.

Lastly, if you need to apply some sort of consistency over the message structure (because for some strange reason the SOAP envelope is not enough and you need your own bespoke envelope to put in the SOAP envelope), please consider using [abstract base types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#abstract), which you then [extend](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivExt) to suite the particular needs of the method. This will allow you to apply consistency, without requiring your service consumers to guess what the "any" might actually be.

Side note. One client I worked at had a generic message structure such as yours. One of the reasons was they wanted a consistent way to report success or error in their web service responses. So in the to of their bespoke response envelope was a element to indicate success or failure and all was good...

...except for the consumers of the service, who now needed to write extra code no only checking for SOAP faults, but also checking if the bespoke error flag was set.

...and except for when we wanted to put a load balancer in front of our services, because it didn't natively support our bespoke error element. It did however support SOAP faults and http status codes :/

**UPDATE**

A simpler way to put it. The operation violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

If an operation accepts "Any", I should expect that any valid xml element I pass to the operation will work. However only certain XML elements are allowed. The only way to know which types are allowed is to know the details of the operation. In other words, the operation is less flexible than advertised.

The above update was modified from the excellent answer at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/198100/37491

Comment: Thanks Tom for the detailed response. Actually it's working fine for us. One way that we found and worked for us is still have the Any element on the Tibco side but provide the consumer with the XSD they need to generate their concrete classes. We needed to create these XSDs anyway for our parsing and they same XSDs will be used on the consumer side. For payload, we are using A Choice element.

Comment: @Derar, that's still a bespoke approach, which requires extra effort from everyone involved, which in turn increases costs.

Comment: @Derar, I've added an update based on a very good answer over at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I disagree that this will necessarily increase costs - it's simply a decision between dynamic and static behavior. Many of Tibco's solutions are primarily message-oriented, not RPC oriented - a different paradigm. One is not necessarily better than the other - take a look at Actor patterns, for example. Also, there are many reasons why you may want your own envelope structure inside of SOAP - particularly to preserve the message as it moves through the platform. SOAP generally is not the only invocation method used for enterprise solutions.

Comment: @ShadowChaser you can get dynamic behaviour using abstract base types and extensions. It provides far more clarity that using "Any" and done right, doesn't violate the Liskov substitution principle. Regarding custom envelopes with SOAP, I've never encountered one that actually added more value than pain, but your experience may be different. However preserving the message as it moves through the platform still doesn't require or justify using "Any".

Comment: Completely understand your point about the Liskov substitution principle, but bear in mind XML is inherently designed to compose documents - not to be an object-oriented programming language. Either way, the transmitted XML ends up being very similar regardless of the approach used.

I also talked with many of my colleagues about custom message envelopes in the SOAP body, and everyone agreed they were the way to go - including the developers, architects, and TIBCO professional services. Depends on the specific platform needs, I imagine.

Comment: @ShadowChaser yep the resulting XML when using Any and extensions is very similar, it's the interface that is significantly different, which is the point I'm trying to make. However, there isn't enough room to discuss this properly here. If you truly believe custom envelopes and Any are the way to go, come over to windyroad.com.au, lodge a support request and we go through some worked examples together. When we are done we can update this entry with the results. I'll be happy to admit if I'm wrong as it at least means I've learnt something new. Challenge accepted?